# another communication to odroid xu4 to launch rosnode

Tags: ros, odroid, pixhawk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,all. I want to use odroid controlled pixhawk quadrotor outside. And does anyone knows that any communications or cases i can use to launch ros in the odroid. I known wi-fi connection with odroid indoor to launch ros-node.
Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219142/another-communication-to-odroid-xu4-to-launch-rosnode/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the question is not clear. I just use **upstart service** to launch rosnode as soon as the odroid is restart.

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0